# Compile Groovy and Kotlin?

Tags: gradle, groovy, kotlin

I'm working on a small project with Groovy and Kotlin, and my Kotlin code depends on my Groovy code, not the other way around. However, Kotlin compiles my code first instead of Groovy, and, as a result, I get errors like `Unresolved reference: SiteRepository`

Any suggestions how I can fix this, by either changing the build sequence, or Kotlin depending explicitly on Groovy, or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It can be done like so:

### After 4.10

**Kotlin First:**

```
//compileKotlin.dependsOn = compileKotlin.taskDependencies.values - 'compileJava'
compileGroovy.dependsOn compileKotlin
compileGroovy.classpath += files(compileKotlin.destinationDir)
classes.dependsOn compileGroovy
```

### Before 4.10

**Groovy First:**

```
compileGroovy.dependsOn = compileGroovy.taskDependencies.values - 'compileJava'
compileKotlin.dependsOn compileGroovy
compileKotlin.classpath += files(compileGroovy.destinationDir)
classes.dependsOn compileKotlin
```

or **Kotlin First:**

```
compileKotlin.dependsOn = compileKotlin.taskDependencies.values - 'compileJava'
compileGroovy.dependsOn compileKotlin
compileGroovy.classpath += files(compileKotlin.destinationDir)
classes.dependsOn compileGroovy
```

To be clear, you get to choose whether your Kotlin code depends on Groovy or Groovy on Kotlin, but you don't get to have it both ways.

Comment: This seems to be working for the main sources. However, this workaround does not work for me when I try to reference a Kotlin file in Groovy Testing code. I also tried changing `compile[Language]` to `compileTest[Language` and `classes` to `testClasses`. It didn't help either though.

Comment: I was getting an error with this answer. This is what worked for me in the end: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44521266/2938293

Comment: @JaredBurrows It isn't possible as far as I can tell in Gradle 4.6. `org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskDependency` doesn't permit removing task dependencies anymore.

Comment: Yes, for never versions of Gradle), `taskDependencies` doesn't work. When upgrading from Gradle 3.1 to 4.10.2, removing this line fixed it:
`compileKotlin.dependsOn = compileKotlin.taskDependencies.values - 'compileJava'`

Also, seems `classes.dependsOn compileGroovy` is no longer needed.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is not possible to compile Kotlin against Groovy in one module, but you can move Groovy (or Kotlin) in separate module. Groovy will be compiled in jar, and Kotlin now can depend on Groovy code. To help you i wrote simple project, and [publish it](https://github.com/IRus/kotlin-groovy) on github.

**upd 1:**

I create new module and project with kotlin and groovy, and inspect tasks dependencies:

```
./gradlew -m kotlin-groovy:build
:kotlin-groovy:compileKotlin SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:compileJava SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:compileGroovy SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:processResources SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:classes SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:jar SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:assemble SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:compileTestKotlin SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:compileTestJava SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:compileTestGroovy SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:processTestResources SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:testClasses SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:test SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:check SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:build SKIPPED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.587 secs
```

Looks like change order of kotlin and groovy tasks enough. But if we change steps in this way:

```
./gradlew -m kotlin-groovy:build
:kotlin-groovy:compileGroovy SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:compileKotlin SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:compileJava SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:processResources SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:classes SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:jar SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:assemble SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:compileTestKotlin SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:compileTestJava SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:compileTestGroovy SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:processTestResources SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:testClasses SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:test SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:check SKIPPED
:kotlin-groovy:build SKIPPED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.745 secs
```

Build still doesn't work, because of Kotlin doesn't see Groovy.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but according to this: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/kotlin-groovy-and-java-compilation/14903/2 , it seems to be possible. Just don't know how.

Comment: Why you can't introduce additional module?

Comment: Kotlin is applicant to be primary language in any java/groovy project, because of it's safety and language features. So adding an additional module (which is super simple) doesn't look too hard.

Comment: What do you mean with: "Looks like change order of kotlin and groovy tasks enough." ? How did you manage to change this build order?

Comment: In `gradle.build` i wrote: `compileKotlin.dependsOn(compileGroovy)`, than i remove `compileJava` from `compileGroovy`, because first change intoroduced circular dependencу: `compileGroovy.dependsOn.remove('compileJava')`.

Comment: Okay, that changes the build order indeed, but you're right, Kotlin still doesn't see the compiled classes. Strange.

Answer (score 4):

When Gradle 6.1 is released proposed solutions above will not work. You can use a new way of how to solve the original issue.

```
tasks.named('compileGroovy') {
    // Groovy only needs the declared dependencies
    // and not the output of compileJava
    classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
}
tasks.named('compileKotlin') {
    // Kotlin also depends on the result of Groovy compilation 
    // which automatically makes it depend of compileGroovy
    classpath += files(sourceSets.main.groovy.classesDirectory)
}
```

And with Kotlin:

```kotlin
tasks.named<GroovyCompile>("compileGroovy") {
    // Groovy only needs the declared dependencies
    // and not the output of compileJava
    classpath = sourceSets.main.get().compileClasspath
}
tasks.named<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>("compileKotlin") {
    // Kotlin also depends on the result of Groovy compilation 
    // which automatically makes it depend of compileGroovy
    classpath += files(conventionOf(sourceSets.main.get()).getPlugin(GroovySourceSet::class.java).groovy.classesDirectory)
}
```

https://docs.gradle.org/6.1-rc-1/release-notes.html#compilation-order

Comment: So, beautiful! Thanks for highlighting this from release notes.

Comment: With gradle-6.2.2 I cound not adapt your configuration to the scenario where groovy test code depends on kotlin test code. The recommendation [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56128450/4774054) however works perfectly: `compileTestGroovy.classpath += files(compileTestKotlin.destinationDir)`

Comment: This no longer works for Gradle 8.5.  Is there a new way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

For **Gradle 5.2.1** if you want to call Groovy from Kotlin:

```
compileGroovy.dependsOn.remove('compileJava')
compileKotlin.dependsOn compileGroovy
compileKotlin.classpath += files(compileGroovy.destinationDir)
```

Comment: In Gradle 6.0 you cannot remove a dependsOn, but I got this to work with only doing this: `compileKotlin.classpath += files(compileGroovy.destinationDir)`.

Comment: This is really useful.  Is it possible to see an example as well?

Comment: @FranciscoAlbert We moved from Groovy to Kotlin with our application last year. During the transition period we had to support both languages. After some initial setup problems it worked rather smoothly and now all is in Kotlin. If you really want I can tell you more.