# groovy is unable to resolve kotlin classes

Tags: groovy, kotlin

As I was not able to resolve the issue I have with `kotlin`, I decided to return to `groovy` in order to implement the plugin.

However I ran into the issue. I have such project structure.

[image]

In order not to rewrite all classes I decided to reuse classes implemented in `kotlin`.

However my classes `FileProcessingCoreGroovy` & `DownloadCoreGroovy` are unable to resolve class `ProcessStream` and `UnpackStream`.

I thought they should be able freely use each other but I guess I was wrong. What is the problem?

The classes itself are imported just fine by IDE (not marked in red color and so on)

[image]

The console output looks like this (I use another class where I import `PluginUtils` from `kotlin` classes)

```
:clean                                                                           
:compileKotlin (...multiple deprecated messages...)
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE       
:compileGroovy                 
startup failed:                
D:\groovy_apps\MISC\gradle-app-environment-plugin\src\main\groovy\com.lapots.gradle.plugins.appenv\ApplicationEnvironmentGroovyPlugin.g
roovy: 4: unable to resolve class com.lapots.gradle.plugins.appenv.core.PluginUtils
 @ line 4, column 1.
   import com.lapots.gradle.plugins.appenv.core.PluginUtils
   ^
```

Comment: Do you compile the kotlin files before the groovy files?

Comment: Hm. I use default order and according to it, it compiles in order `compileKotlin`, `compileJava`, `compileGroovy`.

Comment: do you get that error at compile or runtime?

Comment: compile-time as I am unable to build the artifact

Comment: @cfrick add console output

Answer (score 26):

Looks like it is not so simple.

See https://discuss.gradle.org/t/kotlin-groovy-and-java-compilation/14903/2

Using suggestions from there, I added

```
compileGroovy {
    dependsOn tasks.getByPath('compileKotlin')
    classpath += files(compileKotlin.destinationDir)
}
```

And it worked.

Comment: You can also duplicate this for test compiling. Just replace compileGroovy with compileTestGroovy and compileKotlin with compileTestKotlin

Comment: It works but Android Studio still think that Kotlin classes don't exist inside of Groovy files and mark them red. I make it works at least in IDEA

Comment: This works, but the best part is have either Java <=> Kotlin, or Java <=> Groovy, or Kotlin => Groovy code.

Answer (score 1):

[vuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44521266/5427663) eventually solved the problem for me.

However, it did not work immediately. Some of my Groovy Spock tests depended on a test utility in Kotlin, and I spent a lot of time figuring out what is wrong. It turned out that I did not move my Kotlin file out of the `src/test/groovy` folder, thus it was not compiled at the right time.

**Make sure that every file is in the correct subfolder according to the language.**
For example:

```
src
+---- main
|   +---- kotlin
|       +---- ...
+---- test
    +---- groovy
    |   +---- ...
    +---- kotlin
        +---- ...
```

For tests, this Gradle code will compile Kotlin before Groovy:

```
compileTestGroovy {
    dependsOn tasks.getByPath('compileTestKotlin')
    classpath += files(compileTestKotlin.destinationDir)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. It has something to do with Kotlin companion objects. I moved static functions from companion object to package level and it started to work.